# How to stretch .divider (for nav) 100% to width of container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I stretch the black .divider the entire width of this container?

Setting width to 100% is not working of course inner container has margins set accordingly. How can I set width to outer container margins so it looks like it's 100% stretched across the nav container?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dh3/

[image]

```
      <div class="well sidebar-nav left">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
         <li class="divider"></li>  // <-- How to stretch 100% to outer container margins
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->         
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
```

```
body {
padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}
.row-fluid > .sidebar-nav {
    width: 220px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.divider {
  border-top: 1px solid #000 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding comes from the `ul` list so you may try using a div before the list. This will stretch 100%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav left">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divider {
    border-top: 1px solid #000 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;
    height: 1px;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dh3/9/)**

**UPDATE**

I think I found a better solution that does not need any change in markup, now you can have a `li,divider` anywhere in your list. Add this to your CSS:

```
.nav-list {
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-list > li > a, .nav-list .nav-header {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dh3/12/)**

Comment: Well I think it's better than adding another ul (extra markup) plus inline styling

Comment: I like your code! However, to put a twist on this how would I put in a divider right after the "Sidebar"?  Since it's within the <ul> how can I get around that one? http://jsfiddle.net/XNPXB/?

Comment: You're right you can only use this method outside `ul` so you couldn't place a diver in between two links without breaking your list in two. However if you are trying to stylize your .nav-header I would do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/XNPXB/1/). But if you think about the accepted answer it would also make you break your list in two if you wanted a divider inside a list, plus it will add more extra markup

Comment: @JaJ Updated to add new CSS only solution

Comment: would you consider revising your accepted answer? I believe I provided two better solutions for your issue

Comment: Yep, you got it! It's definitely more helpful to the community as well. Your time and help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code according to your requirement.

```
    <div class="container" style="width: 1300px">
  <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="well sidebar-nav left">
        <ul class="nav nav-list" style="width:100%; padding-left:0px;">
            <li class="divider"></li></ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->



    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
```

Check the fiddele http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dh3/10/

Answer (score 0):

Its not showing upto 100% because the  just above have the CSS property overflow hidden, also it have some padding-left, See the updated fiddle to see the changes after removing them

```
    <div class="container" style="width: 1300px">
  <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="well sidebar-nav left">
        <ul class="nav nav-list"style="width:100%; padding-left:0px;">
         <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->



    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dh3/8/

Comment: ok cool!  But how do I keep the padding on the left for nav menu items and how to fix the overflowed bar to the right of the nav?  I was hoping for something more seamless (probably not possible) than have to go in and restyle everything (bar overhang to right, padding for menu-items) just to get a divider to stretch 100%?  Not sure if there is every an easy answer with styling.  =)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to fix this:

**1. Just edit the CSS to make use of negative margins (not very dynamic, but quick and simple).**

I added this to get the right effect:

```
.nav-list .divider {
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}
```

The drawback with this is that it depends on you not changing any sizes or zooming.

**2. Use some javascript / jQuery.**

Alternatively, you can use a bit of jQuery (assuming you already are using for that menu) so that it doesn't really matter at what size the page is opened.  I used this little snippet:

```
var resizeDivider = function() {
    var navWidth = $('.sidebar-nav').width();
    var navIndent = $('.nav-header').css('margin-left');
    var divider = $('.divider');
    divider.width(navWidth);
    divider.css('margin-left', navIndent);
}
$(function () {
    resizeDivider();
});
```

This may be a little heavy-handed based on your use case, though.  One of these solutions should fit you, though!